# write [2] next to an equation

Tags: equations, amsmath, brackets

I have a code that looks like this :

```
\[\Omega_\Lambda{}_0 = 0,6911 \tag {2}\]
```

in the pdf the `(2)` has round parentheses. I would like square brackets `[]` to figure instead : `[2]`

Can you give me the correct code. 
Thanks

Comment: Please provide working documents, not only fragments!

Comment: Please advise if the use of square brackets instead of round parentheses to surround equation numbers is supposed to apply to a *single* otherwise-unnumbered equation or to many such equations.

Comment: @Werner - Please consider reopening this question: The posting's objective appears to be to alter the look of a *single* equation tag, rather than to obtain a method by which the format of all equation numbers should be modified. To achieve this objective, the `\tag*` method is the way to go -- and this method hasn't been mentioned (yet) in the earlier posting.

Comment: Sorry, I am a latex ignorant. I'm not a programmer that is why I ask so dumb questions. I am not used to this website and haven't understood yet how everything works. You have been very helpful anyhow !!!

Answer (score 4):

I doubt the usefulness of `\[...\]` together with `\tag` but here you are, it's even in the `mathtools` documentation (from which I stole this ;-))

I also don't understand `\Lambda{}_{0}` but... -- well ;-)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets}

\begin{document}

\[\Omega_\Lambda{}_0 = 0,6911 \tag {2}\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you were very helpful. I am a latex ignorant so the simpler the answer the better hhhh. 70% of what is said on this website is outlandish to me. You just gave me a great piece of advice. Use the mathtools documentation, which I didn't even check and know of its existance. hhh

Answer (score 3):

For a one-off tag assignment using square brackets, you could type `\tag*{[2]}` for the equation in question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[textwidth=5cm]{geometry} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\[
a+b=c \tag*{[2]}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answers. I am a latex ignorant so the simpler the answer the better hhhh. 70% of what is said on this website is outlandish to me. Anyhow, your help was very useful !!!